# Heroku `git push heroku master` getting error code H81

Tags: angular, heroku

Hello I try to deploy to Heroku but I still accept error code H81 I do `git push heroku master` and it still doesn't work.

This is the `heroku logs -t`

```
2020-01-21T17:14:25.962640+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET 
path="/favicon.ico" host=m-markets.herokuapp.com request_id=d9aca2e1-6629-43de-8e16-556d8d38812d 
fwd="87.71.26.143" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-01-21T17:19:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user itzikking1@gmail.com
2020-01-21T17:20:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: 
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/db636abf-1eaa-4a9d-a7d6-cba4cb98e1d0/activity/builds/2774cb20-2d8d- 
4046-ad8c-6d722b2381f8
```

Angular project server.js file

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/m-markets'));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
const fullPath = path.join(__dirname + '/dist/m-markets/index.html');
console.log(" Fetching from.." + fullPath);
res.sendFile(fullPath);
})

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Also i do
`git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger deployment"
git push heroku HEAD:master`

And it gives me

```
Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
```

Comment: Other than your `git commit --allow-empty` call, have you added the app's files to the Git repository and pushed that? `git add . && git commit && git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

That error code means that your app is blank. So, it may be anything in your app startup